# Terraform EB environment not finding subnet with explicit dependency

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform configuration with various AWS resources in one file, including a VPC, three private, three public subnets, and an EB environment.

My Terraform version is 0.12.0, and the AWS provider version is `~> 2.12`
The VPC looks like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "terraform-vpc" {
  cidr_block                       = "${var.cidr_block}"
  assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = true
}
```

My six subnets look like this:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private-a" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-a" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-b" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.3.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-b" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.4.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-c" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2c"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.5.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-c" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2c"
  cidr_block        = "10.0.6.0/24"
}
```

Then, in my aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment resource I have:

```
...

setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = "#{aws_subnet.private-a.id},#{aws_subnet.private-b.id},#{aws_subnet.private-c.id}"
}

setting {
   namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
   name      = "ELBSubnets"
   value     = "#{aws_subnet.public-a.id},#{aws_subnet.public-b.id},#{aws_subnet.public-c.id}"
}

...

depends_on = [
  aws_security_group.default, # created earlier in the same file
  aws_subnet.public-a,
  aws_subnet.public-b,
  aws_subnet.public-c,
  aws_subnet.private-a,
  aws_subnet.private-b,
  aws_subnet.private-c
]
```

The problem is I always get an error that one of the subnets does not exist, for example:

```
Error: ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: 
Invalid option value: '["#{aws_subnet.private-c.id}","#{aws_subnet.private-b.id}","#{aws_subnet.private-a.id}"]' 
(Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'Subnets'): The subnet '#{aws_subnet.private-c.id}' does not exist.
```

It is always related to a different subnet, sometimes one of the private ones used for the `Subnets` option, sometimes one of the public ones used in the `ELBSubnets` option.

What baffles is me is that I have explicitly defined them as dependencies, although I think it should work even without the explicit dependency. And in the `terraform apply` logs all of the subnets are always created before the eb environment:

```
aws_subnet.private-c: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-some-id]
aws_subnet.public-a: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-some-id]
aws_subnet.public-c: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-some-id]
aws_subnet.public-b: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-some-id]
aws_subnet.private-a: Creation complete after 6s [id=subnet-some-id]
aws_subnet.private-b: Creation complete after 6s [id=subnet-some-id]

...

aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.default: Creating...
```

Upon checking in AWS, everything the subnets are created as expected and as reported by `apply`. What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Why are you using `#{aws_subnet.public-a.id},#{aws_subnet.public-b.id},...` syntax? That looks wrong to me and should be `${aws_subnet.public-a.id},${aws_subnet.public-b.id},...`. Also you don't need the `depends_on` when you have interpolation for those resources in the resource that depends on those things as Terraform can work this out automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I had missed that part all the time, I can't believe it. I'm sorry for taking your time for such a careless mistake...

Answer (score 0):

As ydaetskcor mentioned in the interpolation of the subnets and used # instead of $, so `#{aws_subnet.public-a.id},#{aws_subnet.public-b.id}` should be `${aws_subnet.public-a.id},${aws_subnet.public-b.id}`.

Comment: I'm not sure this really justifies an answer because it won't help other people in this case as it's just a typo. I voted to close the question as a typo and think that's probably the best bet here.